# IE is not able to display tinymce icons

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tinymce

My code is not able to display the tinymce Icons ...below is my code

```
tinymceSettings: {
        theme : "advanced",
        tinymcePlugins: "style,paste,directionality,advimage,advlink",
        theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,|,fontselect,fontsizeselect,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
        theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left"
        //theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom"
    extended_valid_elements :"a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],font[face|size|color|style]"
}
```

Please help me out

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add more information. Can you show a screen shot of what it looks like? Does it work in FF?

Comment: Could it be that the icons are not uploaded, or maybe misplaced?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

The problem lies in the definition of the button interface. You're using `|` to indicate a separator when you should use `separator` to do that.

Change the line to:

```
theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,fontselect,fontsizeselect,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,outdent,indent,separator,undo,redo,separator,forecolor,backcolor",
```

You can scan through the documentation for theme_advanced_buttons1 here if you like. http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/theme_advanced_buttons_1_n